# Подключение к MSSQL удалённого сервера

Tags: php, sql-server

PHP **7.0.4**, x86
Драйвер **php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll**

На локальной машине подключается

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db', 'sa', '1111');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Но по внешнему адресу нет

```
sqlsrv:Server = IP; // ни так
sqlsrv:Server = IP,1433 // ни так
sqlsrv:Server = IP\SQLEXPRESS,1433 // и ни так
```

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] Поставщик TCP: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.

---

<sub>Через *SQL Server Management Studio* подключается на SRV\SQLEXPRESS</sub>

---

<sup>*Диспетчер конфигурации SQL Server* в настройке *Native Client* показывает порт по умолчанию 1433, который проброшен в маршрутизаторе</sup>

---

<sup>netstat не знает про 1433</sup>

Comment: а на сервере разрешены удалённые подключения? ошибка-то вроде как раз об этом говорит

Comment: @Anatol, как разрешить? В Management Studio свойствах сервера стоит **разрешение на удалённые соединения с этим сервером**. В свойствах базы никаких разрешений нет

Comment: настройки ОС смотрите, фаервол и тд

Comment: @Anatol, фв отключён

Comment: Я так понял проблема в том что удаленное подключение для sa не настроено. Гуглите в этом направлении, я не уверен как это в mssql настраивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Диспетчер конфигурации SQL Server** → **Протоколы для SQLEXPRESS**

Перевести **TCP/IP** в состояние *Включено*
Вкладка **IP-адреса**, где IPAll установить **TCP-порт** 1433
Перезапустить службу

[image: TCP-порт]

<sub>О, этот божественный доступ</sub>

```
0.0.0.0:1433           SRV:0                  LISTENING
```

Comment: Зашёл исключительно по ip адресу, порт 1433 стандартный, указывать не требуется `PDO('sqlsrv:Server=IP;Database=db', 'sa', '1111');`