# Не могу из докер-контейнера c asp.net соединиться с удаленным sql-server

Tags: sql-server, docker

Компьютер на котором запущен докер контейнер имеет адрес 192.168.0.10 Компьютер, на котором работает sql сервер имеет адрес 192.168.2.12 Из контейнера адрес 192.168.2.12 пингуется. Однако попытка открыть соединение с БД на sql сервере из докера навечно зависает на строке

conn.Open();

Строка соединения:

"Data Source=192.168.2.12,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=user;Password=12345"

Если же соединяться с sql сервером не из контейнера, то соединение устанавливается нормально.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: а на компьютере с sql server настроен firewall? tcp ip у вас включено? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596702/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-mssql-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0/596788#596788

Comment: Да, все включено. Все компьютеры нормально соединяются, только из докер-контейнеров соединения не происходит.

Comment: Если ли лог со сторны MySQL сервера? Стоит ли ограничение на подсеть в настройках  базы.

Comment: Похоже, что проблема с версиями TLS. В настройках безопасности SQL сервера проблема.